# Printing the time of files in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am trying to print the time of all the files using the following shell script. But I see that not always bytes 42 to 46 is the time, as it changes due to more/less bytes in username and other details. Is there another way to fetch the time?

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in `ls `
do
    #echo `ls -l $file`
    echo `ls -l $file | cut -b 42-46`
done
```

Comment: Read [my answer](http://superuser.com/questions/447684/fastest-way-to-get-creation-and-last-modification-times-of-a-lot-of-files/469902#469902) to [Fastest way to get creation and last modification times of a lot of files](http://superuser.com/questions/447684/fastest-way-to-get-creation-and-last-modification-times-of-a-lot-of-files) about using a custom date format with `ls`, or the Perl operators `-A,`-C`, and `-M`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use awk.

Try `ls -l | awk '{ print $6 $7 $8}'`

This will print the 6th, 7th and 8th fields of ls -l split by whitespace

If the fields are different for you change the numbers to adjust which fields.

Comment: You may want to add spacing too `ls -l | awk '{ print $6" "$7" "$8}'`.

Comment: if i do the same thing with date, i get an error.
echo `date | awk '( print "$1" )'`

Comment: You need to use curlies - ie { and } not parentheses

Comment: yeah. works fine. but i am using the cut as the date has output of hours,minutes and seconds where as ls -l gives only hours and minutes.
Thanks daveh

Comment: This will fail if filenames contain spaces, newline chars etc. I like `stat`.

Comment: Shouldnt fail on spaces in filenames, as the filename is the last entry in ls -l all of the requested stuff is before and thus remains in sequence. If you were using this to gather filenames you would run into an issue, yes.

Comment: @daveh: Yes you are correct. But printing half a filename may end up being confusing, esp. if there are many similar files. I just dislike parsing `ls`. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 2):

The output from `ls` varies depending on the age of the files.  For files less than about 6 months old, it is the month, day, time (in hours and minutes); for files more than about 6 months old, it prints the month, day, year.

The `stat` command can be used to get more accurate times.

For example, to print the time of the last modification and file name of some text files, try:

```
stat -c '%y %n' *.txt
```

From the manual:

```
   %x     Time of last access
   %X     Time of last access as seconds since Epoch
   %y     Time of last modification
   %Y     Time of last modification as seconds since Epoch
   %z     Time of last change
   %Z     Time of last change as seconds since Epoch
```

[man stat](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?stat)

Comment: Also, see the `-t` option to modify the format used for the times printed by `%y`.